# What is this matrix decomposition, and is it useful for solving least square problems?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, svd

I am numerically studying a class of matrices $A$, size $n \times n$, that are *singular*, but can be decomposed into
$$A = V D V^T,$$
where $D$ is a (non-singular) square, diagonal matrix of size $m \times m$ and $V$ is a matrix of size $n \times m$.
Does this decomposition have a name?

I am trying to solve for
$$ \arg \min_x ||A x - b||^2.$$
My question is: is the known decomposition useful in any way?
Had it been an SVD decomposition, it would [immediately](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#Pseudoinverse) give the answer to the equation.

In general $n < m$, and an example of $V$ could be

```
V = [[-1, -1,  0, -1,  0,  0,  0,  0],
     [ 1,  0, -1,  0,  0, -1,  0,  0],
     [ 0,  1,  1,  0, -1,  0, -1,  0],
     [ 0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  0,  0, -1],
     [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  1]]
```

$D$ can then be any diagonal matrix, but with the identity matrix, we have

```
A = [[ 3, -1, -1, -1,  0],
     [-1,  3, -1,  0, -1],
     [-1, -1,  4, -1, -1],
     [-1,  0, -1,  3, -1],
     [ 0, -1, -1, -1,  3]]
```

which has rank $n - 1$.

Comment: what does it mean singular for you?

Comment: @FedericoFallucca $Determinant = 0$. For my system $A$ has $rank = n - 1$.

Comment: @Jolle I'm having a hard time finding a reference that defines this exactly, but this is essentially equivalent to a [signature decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia) (see also [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_form#Real_quadratic_forms)) of a symmetric matrix. Note that without loss of generality, we can always take $D$ to be a matrix whose diagonal entries are $\pm 1$, and if $W$ is a matrix such that $[V\ \ W]$ is invertible then we can write
$$
VDV^T = \pmatrix{V & W} \pmatrix{D&0\\0&0} \pmatrix{V&W}^T.
$$

Comment: Thank you @BenGrossmann -- your idea is much appreciated! I forgot to specify that in my case $n < m$, so I cannot take your approach. I have updated the question -- sorry for not being precise.

Comment: $A$ is a symmetric matrix and what you do is decompose the quadratic form $q(x)=x^TAx$ into a sum of squares (of linear combinations) with coefficients of any sign. Certainly the signature decomposition falls into that class, you can extend the sum-of-squares with arbitrary additional terms with coefficient (and diagonal element) zero.

Comment: Again thank you very much for all your help. It is giving me some nice stuff to read, but I still have not found anything fruitful. In formulating my question I tried to simplify it, but I realize now that this made it harder to understand. I have rephrased my question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4623500/a-fast-way-to-solve-vector-equations-with-matrix-a-v-d-k-vt-for-various-d Any further help would be greatly appreciated.