# A fast way to solve vector equations with matrix $A = V D_k V^T$ for various $D_k$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, svd

I am numerically studying a class of matrices $A$, size $n \times n$, that are *singular*, but can easily be decomposed into
$$A = V D_k V^T,$$
where $D_k$ is a (non-singular) square, diagonal matrix of size $m \times m$ with only positive elements, and $V$ is a matrix of size $n \times m$.  We have $n < m$ and $A$ has rank $n - 1$.

I am studying this for a fixed matrix $V$, for instance

```
V = [[-1, -1,  0, -1,  0,  0,  0,  0],
     [ 1,  0, -1,  0,  0, -1,  0,  0],
     [ 0,  1,  1,  0, -1,  0, -1,  0],
     [ 0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  0,  0, -1],
     [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  1]]
```

but for lots of different $D_k$, and am trying to solve
$$ \arg \min_x ||A x - b||^2$$
for various $b$.

Are there any precomputations of $V$ that would be helpful in solving these kind of equations for various $D_k$?

Had it been an SVD decomposition, it would [immediately](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#Pseudoinverse) give the answer to the equation.

Comment: So you are saying that $V$ has rank $n-1$. Then it could be helpful to factorize $V$ with $n-1$ as internal dimension.

Comment: @LutzLehmann yes, this is possible with e.g. SVD, but I don't see how that helps in the further calculation. Would you care to elaborate what you are thinking? Thanks a ton for your help.

Comment: I see how that could reduce the pseudo inverse calculation to a n x n instead of n x m, which is something indeed, but not massive.